# EXEC xp_dirtree

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ms-access, extended-stored-procedure

I developed a stored procedure with a call to this extended SP

```
EXEC xp_dirtree @path, 1, 1
```

Database: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

I run the stored procedure from different sources:

- ASP. Net with user dbo
- MS Access with user dbo
- MS Access with user test
- SQL Server Management Studio with user dbo
- SQL Server Management Studio with user test

All are OK except:

- MS Access with user test

In this case, the SP cannot find files inside the folder.

Despite that I have no problems in:

- MS Access with user dbo (same app)
- SQL Server Management Studio with user test (same user)

The code from MS Access is:

```
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdef.ReturnsRecords = False
qdef.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("[dbo_Estados]").Connect
Dim sql As String
sql = "EXEC EnviarMails"
qdef.sql = sql
qdef.Execute
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: GRANT execute on xp_dirtree to test; should do it. The MsAccess code posted is executing EnviarMails does the user test have permissions to execute that as well

Comment: I just made this: GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.xp_dirtree TO public
And to the EnviarMails too. No problems with permissiones on SP. But it is returning no files

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think this one may need sysadmin permissions.  Unfortunately, its undocumented and unsupported by Microsoft.  I'd highly suggest using CLR or some other way to get this information.  Since it's undocumented and unsupported, MS may remove it in the future and not tell you.

Answer (score 4):

The undocumented Stored Procedure `xp_dirtree` [requires the **sysadmin** fixed server role](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1328523-391-1.aspx) in order to see any files when the procedure is called.

Adding this role to your user test should enable you to see the results.

It is also worth repeating what has been mentioned in the comments; As this is an undocumented feature of SQL Server it could be removed in a future version and an alternative method of performing this should be used for production workloads.

Comment: If I undestand, I need to give a super high permission to the user? I think this is not an option. I wil try CLR. Any important disadvantage with CLR?

Comment: That's correct, sysadmin is effectively the highest level permission you can give a user. CLR should be a good fit for your purposes as long as you're careful (e.g. setting database to Trustworthy & baring in mind that any vulnerabilities that are in your code could now exist on your SQL Server)